# phalcon 2.0.13 set data with magic setter to related model

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model, phalcon

I have a problem with phalcon model magic getter and setter. 
I want to update like this tutorial : 
https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#storing-related-records

But the thing is my proj is multi module and separated models folder.

So I have to use alias for hasOne and belongsTo

```
$this->hasOne('user_id', '\Models\UserProfile', 'user_id', array('alias' => 'UserProfile'));
```

and

```
 $this->belongsTo('user_id', '\Models\CoreUser', 'user_id', array('alias' => 'CoreUser'));
```

What i want to do is like this.

```
$CoreUser = new CoreUser();
$user = $CoreUser->findFirst(array(
        //...condition here to find the row i want to update
     ));

$user->assign($newUserData);

$user->setUserProfile($newProfileData); 

$user->update();
```

But above this code only save user data and don't save Profile data at all. (have profile data -- confirmed)

So do you have any idea what the error is? if u know, Please help me or give me a tip.

Comment: Does the method `setUserProfile()` exist on `$user`? Otherwise just use `$user->userProfile = $newProfileData`

Comment: Could you also update your answer with the contents of `$newProfileData` please ?

Comment: $user->userProfile = $newProfileData or $user->UserProfile = $newProfileData is not working .. why is it? it should work like in vokuro example :(

Comment: $newProfileData = array('first_name' => 'John', 'last_name' => 'PHP');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
$profile = $user->UserProfile;
```

You should instantiate a new `UserProfile` object

```
// find your existing user and assign updated data
$user = CoreUser::findFirst(array('your-conditions'));
$user->assign($newUserData);

// instantiate a new profile and assign its data
$profile = new UserProfile();
$profile->assign($newProfileData);

// assign profile object to your user
$user->UserProfile = $profile;

// update and create your two objects
$user->save();
```

Note that this will always create a **new** `UserProfile`. If you want to use the same code to update and create a `UserProfile`, you can maybe do something like:

```
// ...

// instantiate a (new) profile and assign its data
$profile = UserProfile::findFirstByUserId($user->getUserId());

if (!$profile) {
    $profile = new UserProfile();
}

$profile->assign($newProfileData);

// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it now.. when assigning like $user->UserProfile = $newUserProfile; 
$newUserProfile should b a Model Object.

So my new code is

```
$CoreUser = new CoreUser();

$user = $CoreUser->findFirst(array(
    //...condition here to find the row i want to update
 ));
$profile = $user->UserProfile; //$profile is now model object which related to $user

//assign new array data 
$profile->assign($newProfileData);
$user->assign($newUserData);
/*
* can also assign one by one like
* $user->first_name = $newProfileData['first_name'];
* but cannot be like $profile = $newProfileData or $user->UserProfile = $newProfile
* since it's gonna override it the model with array
*/
$user->UserProfile = $profile;   

$user->update(); // it's working now
```

Thanks to @Timothy for the tips too .. :)

Comment: btw, there is no need to initialize `$CoreUser`. You can statically run a query on the `CoreUser` class. Like this: `$user = CoreUser::findFirst(['your-conditions']);` This will save you a line of code :)

Comment: btw, that $user->UserProfile = $profile; doesn't apply "/Models/Base::update() " method? /Models/Base the class which userprofile extends which i create as base model for all models..

Comment: If I am interpreting your code correctly, then `$user->UserProfile` will `create` a new profile instead of `update`-ing one. Therefor, it won't call your `/Models/Base::update()` but `::create()` instead. Is that what you are trying to ask?

Comment: yes. should b called create() or update().. but create() method also haven't been called.. coz i have some default columns and default values combined in Base model. but in db, only null on default columns.. :( .. look like these magic methods are not fit for me

Comment: I added an answer, hopefully that will clear things up!